# C++ sapi: User input, edit voice out

Tags: c++, sapi

```
#include <sapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//User inputs what is to be said//
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::wstring input;
        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter text:\n";
            std::getline(std::wcin, input);

            hr = pVoice->Speak(input.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    pVoice->Release();
    pVoice = NULL;
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The code above allows a user to input what they want to have spoken and works perfectly.

Below is the MSDN method of changing pitch and any other similar action is done the same way.

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(L"This sounds normal <pitch middle = '-10'/> but the pitch drops half way through", SPF_IS_XML, NULL );
```

I want to change the pitch, but can't figure out how to do the same action with the code I have.

Comment: So the question isn't really about the SAPI, it's about string manipulation.

Comment: I think it's more sapi related. The method from MSDN manipulates the audio out using the `<pitch middle = '-10'/>` method which is strictly a sapi thing. If that action is manipulating the string, I would not now how it is accomplishing it.

Comment: According to your question, changing the pitch means adding meta information to parts of the string. The only SAPI-related thing in there is the content of the block added. To answer the question, though, the added content could be anything and it would work the same way.

Comment: The string will not be known until the user inputs it, then immediately goes through the code. So I could write a function that runs after the user inputs their information, that opens `input`, adds the pitch change, then continues on with the audio output? I ask that as a question because I wouldn't know if "opening" a string like that, then editing it was possible.

Comment: Yes, you can change the string. That's part of string manipulation, and C++, unlike some other languages, allows strings to be modified directly after being created, meaning you don't have to create new strings in order to manipulate them. You might want to look through some examples of `std::string` to see what you can do with them. The same things can be done with `std::wstring`, but with `wchar_t` rather than `char`.

Comment: Good, I can do it to `wstring`. Getting this to work is going to take some time. Any last pointers or tips to help me along my way? Maybe key words that involve string manipulation?

Comment: Go through a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), look for things that are relevant, and play around with the examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I figure it out, Ill post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concentrate the XML instruction like that

```
std::wstring input;
std::getline(std::wcin, input);
pVoice->Speak(std::wstring(L"<pitch middle = '+10'>"+input).c_str(), 0, 0);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is roughly 22-23 days old, but I decided to take a shot at it. I haven't been able to get all the voices at my disposal to change pitch on the fly, but MS Anna definitely can.

```
#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

void SetVoice(CComPtr<ISpVoice>  _cpVoice, std::wstring _voiceName)
{
    IEnumSpObjectTokens *pProfileEnum;
    SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_VOICES, NULL, NULL, &pProfileEnum);

    unsigned long l;
    pProfileEnum->GetCount(&l);

    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
       CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> IT;
       pProfileEnum->Item(i, &IT);
       WCHAR *wptr;
       IT->GetId(&wptr);
       CSpDynamicString dstrDefaultName;
       SpGetDescription(IT, &dstrDefaultName);
       if(wcsncmp(dstrDefaultName, _voiceName.c_str(), _voiceName.size()) == 0){
            _cpVoice->SetVoice(IT);
       }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    CComPtr<ISpVoice>   cpVoice;
    CComPtr<ISpAudio>   cpOutAudio;

    HRESULT hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);

    SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOOUT, &cpOutAudio);

    if(nullptr != cpVoice) {
        hr = cpVoice->SetOutput(cpOutAudio, FALSE);
    }

    SetVoice(cpVoice, L"Microsoft Anna - English (United States)");
    if(cpVoice) {
        cpVoice->Speak(L"<pitch absmiddle=\"+10\">This is a really high pitched voice</pitch> <pitch absmiddle=\"-10\"> but the pitch drops half way through</pitch>", SVSFIsXML | SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak, NULL);
    }
    puts("Press any key to continue...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```